# SubFolders.Item(I) gives errorcode 800A0005 Runtimeerror invalid Procedure Call

Tags: vbscript

I have created a vbs example to illustrate my problem.

In the development environment in which I work I have no 'each' construction available. Therefore I have to work with 'item'-iteration.

ShowFolderList1 works fine but ShowFolderList2 generates the error.

Can you help me to correct syntax?

ShowFolderList1("C:\Windows") shows me the list of folders in the specified directory.
ShowFolderList2("C:\Windows") gives errorcode 800A0005 Runtimeerror invalid Procedure Call at "F1 = FOL.SubFolders.Item(i)".

Sub ShowFolderList1(folderspec)

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FOL = FSO.GetFolder(folderspec)

s = ""
For Each F1 in FOL.SubFolders
    s = s & F1.Name & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox(s)
```

End Sub

Sub ShowFolderList2(folderspec)

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set FOL = FSO.GetFolder(folderspec)

s = ""
For i = 0 To FOL.SubFolders.Count-1
    F1 = FOL.SubFolders.Item(i)
    s = s & F1.Name & vbCrLf
Next
MsgBox(s)
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

As F1 shall hold an object,

```
F1 = FOL.SubFolders.Item(i)
```

should be

```
Set F1 = FOL.SubFolders.Item(i)
```

On second thought:

The real reason for the error is: the folder object has no `Item` method. You can't traverse folders randomly, only via `For Each`.